# Canvas/JavaScript: How to adjust position of slices in donutgraph using canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a donut pie chart using Canvas. Which is almost done but facing some issue in adjusting position of slices.

Current:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RgLAU/1/
I want 1.) yellow/blue to draw from top 2.) want to write some text inside the donut.
Here is my work upto now:

http://jsfiddle.net/RgLAU/1/

Comment: do you want to display 'text' inside that?, or color portion issue?

Comment: Two issues. 1.) want to display text inside 2. Yellow/blue slices should start from top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arc()` method starts from an horizontal line, on the right of your shape, at middle y position of the shape's height.

You will need to add an offset to each of your start and end angle value.

For your text, I'm not sure what it should display, but setting the context's `textAlign = "center"` and `textBaseline = "middle"` will make it easy to position anywhere.

A rough uncleaned dump of your modified code :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawdountChart(canvas) {
  // text options
  chart.textAlign = "center";
  chart.textBaseline = "middle";
  chart.font = "25px sans-serif";
  // where is our arc start angle
  var offset = 1.5 * Math.PI;
  
  
  this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.lineWidth, this.strockStyle, this.from, this.to = null;
  this.set = function(x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.strockStyle = strockStyle;
  }

  this.draw = function(data) {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
    canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.from + offset, this.to + offset);
    canvas.stroke();
    var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
    var parts = data.parts.pt;
    var colors = data.colors.cs;
    var df = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
      canvas.beginPath();
      canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
      canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df + offset, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100) + offset);
      canvas.stroke();
      df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
    }
    chart.fillStyle = 'white'
    chart.fillText('hello', this.x, this.y);
  }
}
var data = {
  numberOfParts: 4,
  parts: {
    "pt": [20, 30, 25, 25]
  }, //percentage of each parts 
  colors: {
    "cs": ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
  } //color of each part
};

var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
drawDount.set(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, 30, "#fff");
drawDount.draw(data);
```

```html
<canvas id="chart" width="500" height="500" style="background-color:black">  </canvas>
```